# Reading/Writing to a database with SQLiteDB and PyQT5

Tags: python, linux, database, sqlite, pyqt5

I'm having to modify somebody else's code, and that person in unreachable. Its basically the programming for a thermostat and I'm modifying it so that when a certain temperature is exceeded a text message is sent out to me. I've successfully managed to have the thermostat send me the text message (&email at the same time for speed!), however, I'd like for the phone number, email and name of the user to be changed in the application, much like how the target temperature can be changed in the application.

I have successfully created the database at the start, alongside the target temperature using this
code:

```
`db.execute(

"""

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(

id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,

communication_name TEXT,

communication_number TEXT,

communication_provider TEXT,

communication_email_address TEXT

)

""")`
```

and I even manage to create add in a default phone number using these lines of code:

```
`user_id = 1

data = db.select(

"""

SELECT id

FROM user

WHERE id = ?

""",

[user_id]

)

if not data:

communication_number = 5551234567

communication_name = 123

db.insert(

"""

INSERT INTO user(

id,

communication_name,

communication_number)

VALUES(?, ?, ?)

""",

[user_id,

communication_name,

communication_number]

)`
```

Now, on the application side of things, I'm using pyQT5, and I don't know how to access the data from the database in order to overwrite from it or read from it. I do see that "target_temperature" is mentioned when the database is created, when the data is initially inserted into the database, and is also used in the PyQT5 settings page of the application.

Please help, I'd love to be pointed in the right direction here.

I am unsure what to try, I do see that at the top of the database file it imports Location, and in that file I see a variable called "temperature_target" which I believe gets called into action on this static method:

```
`   @staticmethod
    with SQLiteDb() as db:
    data = db.select_one(
    """
    SELECT 
    monitor.id,
    monitor.data_export_last_date,
    monitor.data_export_user_folder,
    monitor.name,
    monitor.sensor_calibration_interval_days,
    location.id,
    location.name,
    location.humidity_minimum,
    location.humidity_maximum,
    location.temperature_target,
    location.temperature_tolerance
    FROM monitor
    JOIN location
    ON location.id = monitor.location_id
    WHERE monitor.id = 1
    LIMIT 1
    """)
    if not data:
    return None
    monitor = Monitor(
    monitor_id=data[0],
    data_export_last_date=data[1],
    data_export_user_folder=data[2],
    name=data[3],
    sensor_calibration_interval_days=data[4],
    location=Location(
    location_id=data[5],
    name=data[6],
    humidity_minimum=data[7],
    humidity_maximum=data[8],
    temperature_target=data[9],
    temperature_tolerance=data[10]
    )
    )
    return monitor
```

I believe something to do with the syntax as I can see variables that are named the same in that file.

However, whilst my database file imports the file Location, my settings file (which creates the settings page) does NOT, even tho it features this line of code

```
`@property
def temperature_target(self) -> int:
return self.parse_int(self.temperature_target_edit.text())

@temperature_target.setter
def temperature_target(self, value: int):
 self.temperature_target_edit.setText(str(value))`
```

Please help, would greatly appreciate anything!!

Comment: That requires some coding. First write a function to read user details from the database, then write a function to update user details in the database, and finally in your PyQT5 application, write methods to read and write user details from the input fields: You need to have QLineEdit elements in your GUI for the user details, similar to what you have for temperature_target.

Comment: Hello, I do have QLineEdit elements in the GUI, I'm just curious on how to have my data displayed in the QLineEdit. I hope that's specific enough.

Comment: Assuming you have a `QLineEdit` widget for the phone number, and another for the email address, ... you need a method to read the data from the database, and then set the text of the QLineEdit widget by calling the `setText` method on your QLineEdit instance.

Comment: Ok, I will try and write the method to read the phone number, that's where I'm stuck. After that I just need to repeat the same for the email, and name etc.

Comment: Consider that Qt provides direct support to SQL databases through the [QtSql](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html) module. I understand you're editing someone else's code and you may not have enough time or resources to rewrite the whole implementation, but consider it for future reference at least. Qt also provides the [QDataWidgetMapper](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html) interface, that allows you to "connect" models to widgets, meaning that you can you can use it along with a QSqlQueryModel in order to achieve proper interaction between the "view" (the widgets) and the model (the db).